# device driver missing config.h

Tags: c, driver, device

So I start reading the book http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/ to write device driver

The problem is the book used 2.6.10 while I'm using 2.6.35.X (on Ubuntu) and "config.h" is missing. I googled the problem and it turned out that config.h is removed.

http://stephane.lesimple.fr/wiki/blog/kernel_2.6.18_linux_config.h_problem suggests 3 solutions and the first 2 don't work to me ( I don't have autoconf.h ). The 3rd solution is the one that is over my head. If anyone can explain the 3rd or has other solutions, I'd appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All -imacros **file** and -include
>   **file** options are processed after all -D and -U options[1](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html).

Each (of the three) option is a way of pointing GCC to a text file with a list of preprocessor defines.
To use option 3, -imacros **a_file** , there is still a need for the file **a_file** , (ie: autoconf.h), the file with the macros or configuration definitions.  On this system it's */usr/src/linux/include/generated/autoconf.h*

```
l /usr/src/linux
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root conman 23 Nov 29 19:37 /usr/src/linux -> linux-2.6.35-gentoo-r12
```

As you can see, this file can occur in 2.6.35.  It seems that maybe configuringi the kernel makes this file; because the content of this file looks tailored to the current kernel.  This looks like a file declaring which drivers are compiled-in(as apposed to compiled as modules).

So:

- First check for the file `find /usr/src/linux/. -name autoconf.h`
  If it is not there, then   configure the kernel (then check again)
- Change CFLAGS in the device driver's Makefile to include -imacros */usr/src/linux/include/generated/autoconf.h*
    `CFLAGS+=-imacros /usr/src/linux/include/generated/autoconf.h`
- Comment out `#include <config.h>` from the driver sources.

[1](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) "3.11 Options Controlling the Preprocessor," GCC Reference